# Substituir linha de configuração com Ansible

Tags: php, vagrant, automatização

**Arquivo:**

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

/** @var \Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader $loader */
$loader = require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
if (PHP_VERSION_ID < 70000) {
    include_once __DIR__.'/../var/bootstrap.php.cache';
}

$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);
if (PHP_VERSION_ID < 70000) {
    $kernel->loadClassCache();
}
//$kernel = new AppCache($kernel);

// When using the HttpCache, you need to call the method in your front controller instead of relying on the configuration parameter
//Request::enableHttpMethodParameterOverride();
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$response = $kernel->handle($request);
$response->send();
$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

**Descrição:**

Quero substituir a linha com o seguinte conteúdo:

```
$kernel = new AppKernel('dev', true);
```

Invés de:

```
$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);
```

**Arquivo main.yml:**

Estou tentando fazer isso, mas não funciona:

```
- name: Change to Symfony development enviroment for reflect the changes directly on the vagrant box
  replace: dest=/vagrant/symfony-standard/web/app.php regexp='$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);' replace='$kernel = new AppKernel('dev', true);' backup=yes
```

**Terminal:**

```
TASK [symfony-standard : Change to Symfony development enviroment for reflect the changes directly on the vagrant box] ***
task path: /vagrant/playbooks/roles/symfony-standard/tasks/main.yml:49
ok: [default] => {"changed": false, "msg": ""}
```

Comment: A propriedade `dest` de `replace` não está [documentada](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/replace_module.html). Tem certeza que é `dest` e não `path`?

Comment: Encontramos outra solução @AndersonCarlosWoss

Answer (score 1):

Também pode usares o modulo lineinfile desta maneira:

```
- name:  Change to Symfony development enviroment for reflect the changes directly on the vagrant box
  lineinfile:
    path: /etc/selinux/config
    regexp: '^\$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);'
    line: '$kernel = new AppKernel('dev', true);'
```

**Referências**
[Ansible documentation for lineinfile module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/lineinfile_module.html)

Comment: é a segunda vez que você solicita uma edição para modificar o escopo de uma resposta alheia. Quando assim coloque suas considerações como comentário ou peça licença ao operador que proferiu a resposta para modificar o conteúdo proposto. Ou faça as considerações em sua própria resposta ou então adicione uma nova resposta a pergunta.

Comment: Desculpa. Como não tenho pontos para poder comentar optei por editar a resposta para completar com mais informação. :(

Comment: As vezes temos que nos colocar na posição do outro operador, por exemplo eu gostei da sua resposta então mandei +1 mas imagina que eu não tivesse gostado e tivesse usado do meu poder de edição para alterar o conteúdo da sua resposta que você acredita estar correta para outra coisa que você não pretendia. Provavelmente você ficaria irado por ter que desfazer as alterações. A página incentiva as edições mas não mude ou acrescente conteúdos apenas facilite para que as resposta sejam visualmente melhor recebidas.

Comment: Eu percebi e optei por fazer uma resposta.
Obrigado pelo +1 e tens toda a razão.

Answer (score 0):

Funcionou dessa maneira:

```
- name:  Change to Symfony development enviroment for reflect the changes directly on the vagrant box
  replace:
    dest: /vagrant/symfony-standard/web/app.php
    regexp: \$kernel = new.*$
    replace: $kernel = new AppKernel('dev', true);
```

E também adicionando esse trecho em `regexp`:

```
\$kernel = new AppKernel\('prod', false\);
```

**Referências**

[Stackoverflow - Replace configuration line with Ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43825090/replace-configuration-line-with-ansible/43825974#43825974)